# Customer invoice should go to paid state without payment transaction and amount due in Odoo 15

Tags: odoo-15

In Odoo 15, i want that when we post an invoice, it should be immediately go to paid state and amount due should be zero, and customer does not need to pay the invoice. this is something like a customer is offered a free product and we don't want the invoice to pay by customer.
Is there any option/configuration present in Odoo 15 or any idea how we can do this, i appreciate any help,

Thanks

Comment: Then why an Invoice it's created?